# Azure web app unhandled exception

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-diagnostics

I have deployed an MVC5 application on Azure as a Web App. I need to configure the web app so that it writes log in case it throws un-handled exception. The log should include the exception message. Is it possible to do in Azure web app? Does anyone how to configure this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to turn on 'Detailed Error Messages' for your Web App. [This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/) gives details about the various logging options.

The error files get created under `/LogFiles/DetailedErrors/` (best accessed via [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)).

Comment: Hi, can this detailed error log files accessible from Log Stream service?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @juvchan: yes, they can be streamed. However, the streaming logic from VS is scoped to the `/LogFiles/Application` folder, and won't see those. But you can stream at the LogFiles root from other clients like `curl`. See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream

Comment: I enabled Application logging and 'Detailed Error Messages' for my web app. I got errors logged under /LogFiles/DetailedErrors/. But it doesn't show me stack trace. Why ?

Comment: It can depend on the specific type of error. e.g. an IIS level error may not have a stack, while an ASP.NET 'yello screen' error should.